# how to disable table fields and text fields at once using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

i am posting the following code which is used to disable text fields of table. now how to modify it such that it also disable text fields for fields say id=name=usn.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
// Disabling Text Fields by default
$("table input[type='text']").each(function () {
    $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
});

$(".inputradio1 input[name=select1]").change(function () {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if (val == "No") {
        $("table input[type='text']").each(function () {
            $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
        });
    } else if (val == "Yes") {
        $("table input[type='text']").each(function () {
            $(this).removeAttr("disabled");
        });
    }
});
});
```

Comment: you want to disable based on id or name?

Answer (score 2):

Use prop('disabled', true) instead.
There's been a few changes since the jQuery 1.6/1.7 versions to distinguish between attributes and properties. Also, there's no need for the loops, you can just apply it to the whole set of matched elements:

```
$("table input[type='text']").prop('disabled', true);
```

Using the following will also make your selector quicker & shorter to read:

```
$("table :text").prop("disabled", true);
```

So in the end, what you are left with is:

```
$("table :text").prop("disabled", true);

$(".inputradio1 input[name=select1]").change(function () {
    $("table :text").prop('disabled', $(this).val() === 'No');
});
```

Comment: but the field usn is enable til now

Comment: I didn't know you could use `:text` on it's own like that. Nice tip.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand the question.

Use [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead.

To disable if `id` or `name` is `usn`.

```
// id's are suppose to be unique. no need for complex find
$("#usn, table input[name='usn']").prop("disabled",true);
```

**EDIT:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    // Disabling Text Fields by default
    $("table input[type='text']").prop('disabled',true);
    $("#usn, table input[name='usn']").prop("disabled",true);

    $(".inputradio1 input[name=select1]").change(function () {
        val disable = $(this).val() == "No";
        $("table input[type='text']").prop("disabled",disable);
        $("#usn, table input[name='usn']").prop("disabled",disable);
    });
});
```

Comment: you are correct but i want to merge both...i.e $("#usn, table input[name='usn']").prop("disabled",true); and $("table :text").prop('disabled', $(this).val() === 'No');

Comment: @SakirAlam I'm not sure I understand, but is my edit closer to what you need?

Answer (score 1):

yes friends i did it...

```
$("table :text").prop("disabled", true);

$(".inputradio1 input[name=select1]").change(function () {
$("#usn, table input[name='usn']").prop('disabled', $(this).val() === 'No') && $("table :text").prop('disabled', $(this).val() === 'No');
});
```

Comment: ah okay, but you don't need the `&&`